# Question on WooCommerce Syntax

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

The Below syntax removes the "Related products" from appearing on the Single Product page, but what does the 20 stand for ?

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20 is the priority. To remove, must use the same priority as the one that was set in the add_action.

Comment: What does this add to what's already there (and accepted)?

Comment: @tf The accepted one is just RTFM. I tried to talk like a human being. Formally, it does not add - for those who can RTFM. But those would not ask that question, right?

Answer (score 1):

> $priority
>       (int) (optional) The priority of the function (as defined when the function was originally hooked). Default: 10

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action